# How to drag and drop into a QTableWidget? (PyQT)

Tags: drag-and-drop, pyqt, qtablewidget

I'm struggling with getting drag&drop to work. I want to be able to drag&drop from a QPushButton into a cell of a QTableView. I've looked at a few tutorials online but seem to be stuck at the first step. The example below is changed from the amazing zetcode tutorial:
http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/dragdrop/

Using the code below, when I drag the button into tableWidget, the dragEnterEvent seems to be get called, but once I hover the mouse over the table, I get that symbol that I'm not allowed to drop over the table, so can never get to the drop event :(

I have to admit I'm fairly new to pyqt, so may be missing something very simple. Would really appreciate any help I could get!
Cheers
Dave

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore


class Button(QtGui.QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, title, parent):
        super(Button, self).__init__(title, parent)


    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if e.buttons() != QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            return

        mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()
        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
        drag.setHotSpot(e.pos() - self.rect().topLeft())

       dropAction = drag.start(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)


    def mousePressEvent(self, e):

        QtGui.QPushButton.mousePressEvent(self, e)
        if e.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            print 'press'


class MyTable(QtGui.QTableWidget):

    def __init__(self, rows, columns, parent):
        super(MyTable, self).__init__(rows, columns, parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        print e.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        print 'blah'

        position = e.pos()
        self.button.move(position)

        e.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)

        e.accept()



class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.button = Button('Button', self)

        self.table = MyTable(2,2,self)
        self.table.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.table.setDragEnabled(True)

        self.setWindowTitle('Click or Move')

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 150)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.setLayout(layout)


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()  


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are setting up drag and drop on a QTableWidget, you also need to re-implement it's `dragMoveEvent`. As per the [docs here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/dnd.html):

> Subclassing Complex Widgets
>   Certain standard Qt widgets provide their
>   own support for drag and drop. When subclassing these widgets, it may
>   be necessary to reimplement dragMoveEvent() in addition to
>   dragEnterEvent() and dropEvent() to prevent the base class from
>   providing default drag and drop handling, and to handle any special
>   cases you are interested in.

```
class MyTable(QtGui.QTableWidget):
    ...
    def dragMoveEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()
```

Also, be aware that while the original tutorial shows how to move a button within a widget without any layouts, your example now has the button managed by a vertical layout. So your `self.button.move(position)` will not work as expected. Though the `dropEvent` should fire properly and you should  be getting the "accepted" drag icon when it hovers a cell.

Comment: Awesome, thank you, that does it! Also thanks for pointing out the layout issue. This was really only a test case for a more complicated case that I'm working on, so will see if that it impacts it at all.